# SQL query join based on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables "customer" and "activation" that I would like to join. Here are their structures:

```
 CUSTOMER                       Activation
 ------------                  ------------- 
 Id      Name                   EntityId       Date_Created       Type
 1       A                         1               2012            EMAIL
 2       B                         2               2011            SMS
 3       C
```

Now, I would like to join those two tables on customer.Id = Activation.EntityId.  However, i want my final table structure to be like this:

```
 Id    Name    Date_Email       Date_SMS       

 1      A        2012             NULL
 2      B        NULL             2011
```

Basically, the columns Date_Email and Date_SMS both come from Activation.Date_Created column. IF Activation.Type is EMAIL, i set Date_Email in my final result to Date_created and set Date_SMS to null. If Activation.type is SMS, i do it the other way.

What i have right now is this:

```
SELECT Customer.Id, Name, Date_Created AS Date_EMail, DATE_Created AS Date_SMS 
from Customer 
inner join Activation ON Customer.Id = Activation.EntityId;
```

Now, i need to make a If-else condition based on Activation.Type column. I am quite new to this and I have not been able to figure this out by googling. I am using Oracle XE database btw

Can someone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Is there only one row in `Activation` for each type and EntityId combination?

Comment: @lc. Yes, EntityId is a foreign key refering to Id in customer table. Sorry, i should have mentioned that

Comment: @hari, are you sure that this is a good design? I'd personally discourage from doing something like that.

Comment: @Yossarian Can you please tell me why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Id, Name, A1.Date_Created as Date_Email, A2.Date_Created as Date_SMS FROM
CUSTOMER C
LEFT JOIN Activation A1 ON C.Id=A1.EntityID AND A1.Type='EMAIL'
LEFT JOIN Activation A2 ON C.Id=A2.EntityID AND A1.Type='SMS'
```

This also adds entity with ID=3, where `Date_Email` and `Date_SMS` are null. I don't know Oracle's syntax, you can remove the ID=3 with something like `WHERE NOT (IsNull(Date_Email) && IsNull(Date_SMS))`

Answer (score 2):

You need to join twice, once for each type (and use a LEFT JOIN to allow nulls):

```
SELECT Customer.Id, Name, ActEmail.Date_Created AS Date_EMail, ActSMS.DATE_Created AS Date_SMS 
FROM Customer 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Activation AS ActEmail ON Customer.Id = ActEmail.EntityId AND ActEmail.Type = 'EMAIL'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Activation AS ActSMS ON Customer.Id = ActSMS.EntityId AND ActSMS.Type = 'SMS'
```